# Emulate display:table with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-tables

How I can emulate display: table with jquery?
Inner divs must fit to the entire outer divs like this:

```
<div style="display:table; width:500px">
<div style="display:table-cell; background-color:red" >aaaa</div>   
<div style="display:table-cell; background-color:green">б</div>
<div style="display:table-cell; background-color:blue">в</div>   
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mjGts/

Comment: You also need to use `table-row`. `table-header-group`, `table-body-group` and `table-footer-group` if you want a truly `<table>`-less table.

Comment: I want to do this without table and table-cell, only javascript.

Comment: The inner divs look like they fit the outer divs to me.  This also does not use any JavaScript

Comment: Ok, sounds great! Please post your previous attempts at using JS or jQuery to create these elements and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: But display:table is not crossbrowser, how to get this effect for ie7 without tables?